# Can AWS ElasticMapReduce take S3 folders as Input?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

i'm currently trying to run a mapreduce job where the inputs are scattered in different folders underneath catch-all bucket in S3.

My original approach was to create a cluster for each of the input files and write separate outputs for each of them. However, that would require spinning up more than 200+ clusters and I don't think thats the most efficient way.

I was wondering if I could instead of specifying a file as input into EMR, specify a folder whose subfolders contain all of the input files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can specify a folder whose sub folders contain all the input files. However in your code you need to ensure that your functions look for the sub-folders in the input, and not just take the main folder as input.